# Merging strategy with a long development branch. How to prevent heavy conflicts in the future merge?

Tags: git, merge, branch

I'm developing a project where I constantly want to make small improvements on `master` branch and push them to production. I have problem because I want to concurrently work on a branch that will be pushed only after a long time.

If I will use different branches on `long_project` and not merge them immediately, one branch will be much ahead. When I will want to launch `long_project` branch to production, will I able to merge it to `master` without destroying all minor work I have done on `master`?

So, how can merge them after a while without destroying any minor changes that I make every day on `master` branch?

Comment: improved header and tags to make the question better searchable. Fixed grammar a little. The question already has a good answer. Hope that this edit will make them both easier to find and use to other SO users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is, after making a small change on `master`, merge `master` into `long project`. That way when you merge `long project` into `master`, there will be fewer (if any) conflicts.

Comment: how could i merge it that way?

Comment: Not sure what you mean; after every small change to `master`, just run `git checkout long-project; git merge master`.

Comment: it won't delete parts of `long project` that is not on `master`?

Comment: Nope, not unless it was on `master` when you branched, and then you _deleted_ it on `master`. If something was just added to `long project`, it would not be removed by the merge. Note that a merge does not overwrite everything in the target with the contents of the source. Rather, it applies the _changes_ that were made since the two branches diverged.

Comment: @DanielsV This answer is right. You may only have a conflict when the same file was changed both in `master` and `long`. But if you merge on a regular basis, you will still remember what the chages were about and it won't be hard to resolve a conflict.